# How to use Stata to pool Cohen's d?

Tags: spss, meta-analysis, stata, effect-size, cohens-d

I am attempting to calculate Cohen's d and then pool those estimates into a summary effect size. Can anyone help? (Stata or SPSS software owned).

Answer (score 3):

In Stata:
1) Download the user-written package -[metan](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456798.html)- from the [SSC software library](http://ideas.repec.org/s/boc/bocode.html):
`. ssc install metan`

2) Assuming you have numbers, means and SDs for two groups, the syntax is of the form:
`. metan n1 mean1 sd1 n0 mean0 sd0`
(Cohen's d is the default method for continuous data)

This gives a fixed-effect meta-analysis. Add the 'random' option for a random-effects meta-analysis, i.e.
`. metan n1 mean1 sd1 n0 mean0 sd0, random`

-metan- has many other options which control various aspects of the output and forest plot.

Comment: Well, we answer quite at the same time. Nice reference for `metan`!

Comment: Thansk everyone - I only have one group - I'm trying to calculate Orwin's (1983) modification of Rosenthal's Failsafe N and it seems like this is only possible using Cohen's d. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

For SPSS, look at :

- [www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/stat-consult/1201/Effect-Size-in-SPSS](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/stat-consult/1201/Effect-Size-in-SPSS)
- [www.spsstools.net/Syntax/T-Test/StandardizedEffectsSize.txt](http://www.spsstools.net/Syntax/T-Test/StandardizedEffectsSize.txt) (maybe better organized)

For Stata, I used [SIZEFX: Stata module to compute effect size correlations](http://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456738.html) (`findit sizefx` at Stata command prompt), but `metan` as suggested by @onestop is probably more featured.